# General solution of boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have to find the general solution of the following boundary value problem with the use of Fourier  method.

$$u_t(x,t)-u_{xxt}(x,t)-u_{xx}(x,t)=0, 0<x< \pi, t>0\\u(0,t=0),t>0$$

$u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$

$u(0,t)=0 \Rightarrow X(0)T(t)=0 \Rightarrow X(0)=0$

$u_t-u_{xxt}-u_{xx}=0 \Rightarrow X(x)T'(t)-X''(x)T'(t)-X''(x)T(t)=0 \Rightarrow \frac{X(x)T'(t)-X''(x)T'(t)-X''(x)T(t)}{X(x)T(t)}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} -\frac{X''(x)T'(t)}{X(x)T(t)}-\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} \left( 1- \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}\right)=\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\lambda \Rightarrow \frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}\left( 1+\lambda\right)=\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\lambda$

$$X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0\\X(0)=0\\ \\T'(t)=-\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}T(t)$$

The characteristic polynomial is $\rho^2+\lambda=0$

1. $\lambda<0: X(x)=c_1 e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+c_2 e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$

   $X(0)=0 \Rightarrow c_1=-c_2$

   $X(x)=c_1( e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}-e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x})$
2. $\lambda=0:$ $X''(x)=0 \Rightarrow X'(x)=c_1 \Rightarrow X(x)=c_1 x+c_2$

   $X(0)=0 \Rightarrow c_2=0$

   $X(x)=c_1 x$ is unbounded.
3. $\lambda>0$: $X(x)=c_1 \cos (\sqrt{\lambda}x)+c_2 \sin (\sqrt{\lambda}x)$

   $X(0)=0 \Rightarrow c_1=0$

   $X(x)=c_2 \sin (\sqrt{\lambda}x)$

In cases 1,3 we find bounded solutions. How will be the form of the general solution?

Comment: Note that $0<x<\pi$ and hence X(x) is bounded in all three cases. Also note that the solution of $T'(t)=-\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}T(t)$ is $T(t)=T(0)e^{-\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}t}$ and hence it is not hard to obtain the general solution.